# How Convolution Layer and Max pooling Work

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, convolution

```
1    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), input_shape=(3, 48, 48), dim_ordering='th'))
2    model.add(Convolution2D(4, 3, 3, activation='relu', dim_ordering='th',init='he_uniform'))
3    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), dim_ordering='th'))
4    model.add(Convolution2D(4, 3, 3, activation='relu', dim_ordering='th',init='he_uniform'))
5    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), dim_ordering='th'))

6    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), dim_ordering='th'))
7    model.add(Convolution2D(8, 3, 3, activation='relu', dim_ordering='th',init='he_uniform'))
8    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), dim_ordering='th'))
9    model.add(Convolution2D(8, 3, 3, activation='relu', dim_ordering='th',init='he_uniform'))
10    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), dim_ordering='th'))
```

above is an example of a pretty simple keras model

The convolution layer at #2 produces as output 4 activation maps, which where learnt from 4, 3x3 kernels. Does the max pool layer at #5 combine these 4 activation maps into a single one?

Also, would it make sense to change #4 to use 8 or 16 kernels? This doesn't make sense to me because i've never seen a CNN example where the # of kernels changes from one layer to the next. It makes sense to me to change the # of kernels between #5 and #7 because the Max pool layer combines the separate activation maps into one. Any intuition on why/how this work?

Answer (score 1):

> Does the max pool layer at #5 combine these 4 activation maps into a single one?

No. As you can see the operation applied is MaxPolling**2D**, so it will be applied only in space and keep the channels. In this case, the output will be 24x24x4, because your stride is 2x2.

> Also, would it make sense to change #4 to use 8 or 16 kernels?

Yes, it will. Actually, that is a good practice, increase the channels dimension before decrease the spatial dimension. That is one insight use in construction of the InceptionV3 architecture for image recognition (you can read it paper [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.00567), sections 2 and 5).

> Any intuition on why/how this work?

I think that in the mentioned paper you can understand better these intuitons